# check and uncheck radio buttons with different names

Tags: jquery, html

I am aware that if we have same names then radio buttons change alternatively. But i want it to be checked and unchecked on click without any relation with another radio.

**js fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Jk6Sk/1/

**html**

```
<input type="radio" name="test1" value="male" checked>Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="test2" value="female" checked>Female
```

**js(I tried):**

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function(){
    if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).prop("checked",true);
    }else{
        $(this).prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

**NOTE:**

it should work like checkbox in short(Is it possible ??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

**jquery:**

```
var radioStatus = false;
$.each($('input[type=radio]'),function(){
    this.radioStatus = $(this).prop("checked") || false;
    $(this).data("status",this.radioStatus);
    $(this).click(function(){
        this.radioStatus = !$(this).data("status")
        $(this).prop("checked",this.radioStatus);
        $(this).data("status",this.radioStatus);
    })
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8dcyD/4/)**

Comment: @Anton My bad, just now I'm in rush to do some stuffs. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 8):

You can `uncheck` all the `check` the current on radio button click event. I would use a class to group these kind of radio buttons to avoid un-wanted inclusion of radio buttons on the page and be specific.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Jk6Sk/3/)**

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function(){   
    $("input[type=radio]").prop("checked",false);
     $(this).prop("checked",true);
});
```

**Edit** based on comments, You need to keep the state of radio button checked state to toggle.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Jk6Sk/19/)**

```
$("input[type=radio]").data('checkedStatus', true);
$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function(){   
    if($(this).data('checkedStatus') == true)
    {
        this.checked = false;
        $(this).data('checkedStatus', false);
    }
    else
    {
         $(this).data('checkedStatus', true);
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont want alternate thing it should work like a checkbox behavior

Comment: The you would use checkbox, why you do not want check box?

Comment: it is present at 1000's of places huge project

Comment: @susheel, you probably need something like, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Jk6Sk/19/